# AVPlayer crash on fullscreen

Tags: avplayer, fullscreen, ios13.3

On iOS **13.3.1** the AVPlayer fullscreen is crashing. Once I rotate the screen the Xcode console shows an error `Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger`.

I have added a symbolic breakpoint, and debugger catch the following error

```
UIWindow:0x108b99360
|   UITransitionView:0x108c53a10
|   |   UIView:0x11be462b0
|   |   |   UIView:0x11beab9d0
|   |   |   UIView:0x11a7c9890
|   |   |   UIView:0x11bebacc0
|   |   |   UIView:0x11be10d00
|   |   UIDropShadowView:0x113c14b00
|   |   |   UILayoutContainerView:0x108bf0790
|   |   |   |   UITransitionView:0x108bc1410
|   |   |   |   |   UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x108ba1590
|   |   |   |   |   |   •UILayoutContainerView:0x108ba25c0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   +UINavigationTransitionView:0x108bc04b0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   +UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x11ae32650
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •UIView:0x11a7c90f0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x280700b60 - "UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide", layoutFrame = {{0, 20}, {667, 425}}, owningView = <UIView: 0x11a7c90f0; frame = (0 0; 667 375); autoresize = W+H; animations = { position=<CABasicAnimation: 0x283e654e0>; bounds.origin=<CABasicAnimation: 0x283e65420>; bounds.size=<CABasicAnimation: 0x283e65460>; position-2=<CABasicAnimation: 0x283e60a20>; bounds.origin-2=<CABasicAnimation: 0x283e60980>; bounds.size-2=<CABasicAnimation: 0x283e60920>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x283ebb900>>>- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UILayoutGuide:0x280700b60'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.Height{id: 8167}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11a7c8e10
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •UIView:0x11ae5b960
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x28071fc60 - "UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide", layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {375, 375}}, owningView = <UIView: 0x11ae5b960; frame = (0 0; 375 375); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2830ff750>; layer = <CALayer: 0x283f1b6a0>>>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11ae598b0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x108ba76e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x11aea33b0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x108cf2320
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11aea3660'Tap to reload'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *NTV.GradientView:0x11ae77740
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x108ba8140
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x108b93db0'Now Playing- Swasthya Sar...'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x108ba64a0'2020-02-14 09:30 - 10:00'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x114c062e0'11:59:23'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UISlider:0x108ba8870 alignmentRect = (16 300.5; 343 18.5) for frame = (14 300.5; 347 19.5);
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIProgressView:0x108c3b7c0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x108c142a0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x108c06090
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIView:0x11bea2880
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x11bea2b60
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIView:0x11bea29f0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x11bea4b20
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x11bea4cf0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11ae01e00'00:00'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x108ba3e70'LIVE'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x113c7d1e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIStackView:0x113c61b80
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x108ba40e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x108cf24f0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIActivityIndicatorView:0x114c16df0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x114c0c0d0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x113c5f6d0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x108cf26c0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x113c4e840
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x108c24720
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x11ae31150
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x108c248f0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x113c37f90'Auto'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIButtonLabel:0x11bea2170'Auto'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIStackView:0x11ae30d80
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<_UIOLAGapGuide: 0x280208a00 - "UISV-distributing", layoutFrame = {{30, 0}, {12, 0}}, owningView = <UIStackView: 0x11ae30d80; frame = (265 10; 94 20); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CATransformLayer: 0x283f1ad80>>>- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for _UIOLAGapGuide:0x280208a00'UISV-distributing'.minY{id: 9088}, _UIOLAGapGuide:0x280208a00'UISV-distributing'.Height{id: 9089}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<_UIOLAGapGuide: 0x28021c600 - "UISV-distributing", layoutFrame = {{62, 0}, {12, 0}}, owningView = <UIStackView: 0x11ae30d80; frame = (265 10; 94 20); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CATransformLayer: 0x283f1ad80>>>- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for _UIOLAGapGuide:0x28021c600'UISV-distributing'.minY{id: 9090}, _UIOLAGapGuide:0x28021c600'UISV-distributing'.Height{id: 9091}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x11ae967d0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x108c54740
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x11aea1a50
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x11a757f70
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *AVRoutePickerView:0x108c4f1d0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x108c227f0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIButtonLabel:0x11be29d30
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11a7c9260- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIView:0x11a7c9260.Height{id: 8163}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *XLPagerTabStrip.ButtonBarView:0x109a18c00
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •XLPagerTabStrip.ButtonBarViewCell:0x11be6b470
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11be6b870
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x280701420 - "UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide", layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {162.5, 40}}, owningView = <UIView: 0x11be6b870; frame = (0 0; 162.5 40); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x28312e910>; layer = <CALayer: 0x283e8db00>>>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11be6b9e0'LIVE CHANNEL'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11be6be40
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •XLPagerTabStrip.ButtonBarViewCell:0x11be6d2a0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11be6d4a0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x280701500 - "UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide", layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {162.5, 40}}, owningView = <UIView: 0x11be6d4a0; frame = (0 0; 162.5 40); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x28312c5a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x283e8d500>>>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11be6d610'LIVE EVENTS'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11be6d880
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIView:0x108c303b0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   _UIScrollViewScrollIndicator:0x108bf1d10
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIView:0x11ae577e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11a7c8f80
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIScrollView:0x109a15000- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIScrollView:0x109a15000.Height{id: 8164}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •UIView:0x11be60eb0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x280701260 - "UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide", layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {375, 173}}, owningView = <UIView: 0x11be60eb0; frame = (0 0; 375 173); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x283eb6f20>>>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UICollectionView:0x109a48400
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •NTV.LiveChannelCollectionViewCell:0x11ae5b750
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11ae5bb60
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11ae5bcd0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11ae5be40
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11ae5c190'NTV'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •NTV.LiveChannelCollectionViewCell:0x11ae5d820
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11ae5da30
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11ae5dba0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11ae5dd10
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11ae5e060'NTV Plus'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •NTV.LiveChannelCollectionViewCell:0x11ae5f3d0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11ae5f5e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11ae5f750
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11ae5f8c0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11ae5fc10'NTV News'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •NTV.LiveChannelCollectionViewCell:0x11be64720
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11be64930
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11be64aa0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11be64c10
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11be64f60'NTV Kohalpur'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •NTV.LiveChannelCollectionViewCell:0x11be66400
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11be66610
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11be66780
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11be668f0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11be66c40'NTV Itahari'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11be61020
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11be61190
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11be603e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11be605b0'NTV'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x11be60a10' MORE SCHEDULE '
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIButtonLabel:0x11ae5a230' MORE SCHEDULE '
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11be61300
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11be61770
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11a7c9a40
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11a73d9c0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UICollectionView:0x1098e3400
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •NTV.EPGCollectionViewCell:0x11be2aad0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11be2ace0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11be2ae50
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11bebbbf0'08:00 - 08:25'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11bebbe60'The News'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11bebc0d0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11bebc240' On Air '
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •NTV.EPGCollectionViewCell:0x11beb0cf0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11beae950
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11beb0220
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11beb0f00'09:00 - 09:30'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11beb1170'Sirjanaka Sarathi'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11beb13e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11beb1550' On Air '
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •NTV.EPGCollectionViewCell:0x11beb3850
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11bebe860
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11bebeec0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11bebf090'Swasthya Sarokar'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11bebf4c0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11bebe9d0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11bebf730' On Air '
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •NTV.EPGCollectionViewCell:0x11aeaf4d0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11aeaf6e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11aeaf850
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11aeafa20'10:00 - 10:15'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11aeafc90'Hamro Kathmandu'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11aeaff00
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11aeb0070' On Air '
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •NTV.EPGCollectionViewCell:0x11aebe350
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11aebe560
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11aebd270
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11aebd440'09:00 - 09:30'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11aebebc0'Sirjanaka Sarathi'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11aebe840
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11aebee30' On Air '
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •NTV.EPGCollectionViewCell:0x11aeb6230
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x113c2beb0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11aea7020
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x108c40a30'Swasthya Sarokar'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11beb9460
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11bea74d0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11beab180' On Air '
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •NTV.EPGCollectionViewCell:0x11aeaba80
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11aeabe90
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x11aeac000
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11aeac1d0'10:00 - 10:15'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11aeac630'Hamro Kathmandu'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11aeaca90
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x11aeacc00' On Air '
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   •UINavigationBar:0x108c24220
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   _UIBarBackground:0x108c37e40
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x11ae59160
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •_UINavigationBarContentView:0x108c4c340
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x280714c40 - "BackButtonGuide(0x108c50bc0)", layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {16, 32}}, owningView = <_UINavigationBarContentView: 0x108c4c340; frame = (0 0; 375 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x283e4b0a0>> layout=0x108c50bc0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x280714d20 - "LeadingBarGuide(0x108c50bc0)", layoutFrame = {{16, 0}, {70, 32}}, owningView = <_UINavigationBarContentView: 0x108c4c340; frame = (0 0; 375 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x283e4b0a0>> layout=0x108c50bc0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x280714e00 - "TitleView(0x108c50bc0)", layoutFrame = {{92, 0}, {231, 32}}, owningView = <_UINavigationBarContentView: 0x108c4c340; frame = (0 0; 375 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x283e4b0a0>> layout=0x108c50bc0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x280716300 - "TrailingBarGuide(0x108c50bc0)", layoutFrame = {{323, 0}, {44, 32}}, owningView = <_UINavigationBarContentView: 0x108c4c340; frame = (0 0; 375 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x283e4b0a0>> layout=0x108c50bc0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x280716220 - "UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide", layoutFrame = {{16, 0}, {343, 44}}, owningView = <_UINavigationBarContentView: 0x108c4c340; frame = (0 0; 375 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x283e4b0a0>> layout=0x108c50bc0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *_UIButtonBarStackView:0x114cdfb30
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x28071f1e0 - "UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide", layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {70, 32}}, owningView = <_UIButtonBarStackView: 0x114cdfb30; frame = (16 0; 70 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x283e81140>> buttonBar=0x28071ef40>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<_UILayoutSpacer: 0x280155680 - "UISV-alignment-spanner", layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {0, 32}}, owningView = <_UIButtonBarStackView: 0x114cdfb30; frame = (16 0; 70 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x283e81140>> buttonBar=0x28071ef40>- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for _UILayoutSpacer:0x280155680'UISV-alignment-spanner'.minX{id: 9224}, _UILayoutSpacer:0x280155680'UISV-alignment-spanner'.Width{id: 9225}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *_UITAMICAdaptorView:0x114cdf6b0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIButton:0x108bcc8d0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x11ae57f00
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x11aea4d00
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *_UIButtonBarButton:0x11aea5ae0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x2807031e0 - "UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide", layoutFrame = {{0, 11}, {37, 10}}, owningView = <_UIButtonBarButton: 0x11aea5ae0; frame = (33 0; 37 44); tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x283f1b620>>>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *_UIModernBarButton:0x11aea5ec0'NTV'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButtonLabel:0x11bea7910'NTV'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *_UIButtonBarStackView:0x108ba78e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x28071eca0 - "UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide", layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {44, 32}}, owningView = <_UIButtonBarStackView: 0x108ba78e0; frame = (323 0; 44 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x283e841c0>> buttonBar=0x28071ebc0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *_UIButtonBarButton:0x114c16590
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UILabel:0x108c4ff70'0'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *_UIModernBarButton:0x114c16770
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x114c14c00
|   |   |   |   UITabBar:0x108bf0990
|   |   |   |   |   _UIBarBackground:0x108bf34f0
|   |   |   |   |   |   _UIBarBackgroundShadowView:0x108bf5d80
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   _UIBarBackgroundShadowContentImageView:0x108bfb190
|   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x113c0bc10
|   |   |   |   |   UITabBarButton:0x113c10f70
|   |   |   |   |   |   UITabBarSwappableImageView:0x113c11530
|   |   |   |   |   |   UITabBarButtonLabel:0x113c11290'Home'
|   |   |   |   |   UITabBarButton:0x113c11ed0
|   |   |   |   |   |   UITabBarSwappableImageView:0x113c12490
|   |   |   |   |   |   UITabBarButtonLabel:0x113c121f0'Live'
|   |   |   |   |   UITabBarButton:0x113c12e30
|   |   |   |   |   |   UITabBarSwappableImageView:0x113c0dea0
|   |   |   |   |   |   UITabBarButtonLabel:0x113c13150'TV Shows'
|   |   |   |   |   UITabBarButton:0x113c13ba0
|   |   |   |   |   |   UITabBarSwappableImageView:0x113c14160
|   |   |   |   |   |   UITabBarButtonLabel:0x113c13ec0'News'
|   |   |   |   |   UITabBarButton:0x108c51190
|   |   |   |   |   |   UITabBarSwappableImageView:0x108c51de0
|   |   |   |   |   |   UITabBarButtonLabel:0x108c51b40'More'
|   UIView:0x108bf0bb0
```

The issue is on iOS 13.3.1 devices and it is working for 12.4.5 devices. I have tried to change the constrains of AMBIGUOUS view but could not resolve the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened because of an infinite loop under `layoutSubviews`. Once I fix that it was solved. Thought the crash appears only on iOS 13, the previous version of iOS has no issue with it.